# What is N editions of Windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I read in msdn that CameraCaptureUI is not supported in N editions of Windows 8. I tried to search in net about N editions but I didn't find. So what is it? Is it ok to use CameraCaptureUI? I hoped it'll work on all editions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Windows N editions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/What-is-Windows-7-N-edition) are the editions of Windows that lack Windows Media Player. The class you're asking about appears to be provided by the components of Windows Media Player, so if Windows doesn't have that, your code won't work. There's nothing you can do to make it work, either you'll have to accept that it won't work, or you'll have to use something else that does the same thing (or something similar).

Comment: Thanks, I'll hope that users who use these editions and my application will be as small as possible.

Comment: And I have a question: is wmp will avaiable on arm devices which hasn't desktop mode?

Comment: @NikeStrike The documentation doesn't say it won't be, so I suppose it will be, but I don't actually know, sorry.

Comment: It's not about media player; it's about the MediaFoundation API. This is what is missing in the N editions. It can be downloaded as an optional extra. CameraCapture in Metromismsupported on any device with a camer - presence can be checked programmatically to fail gracefully.

Comment: @DominicHopton The N editions were created when Microsoft was required by the EC to create a version without Windows Media Player. Some components that were only a required part of the OS for the benefit of Windows Media Player were also dropped, and I (perhaps inaccurately) summarised that as "components of Windows Media Player".

Comment: i think there are only 3 people in the world who actually use the N editions and they are only doing it to verify that Microsoft is fulfilling their legal obligations.  this is not a real-world problem to worry about

Comment: In Windows RT (for arm devices) there aren't WMP and WMC http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8_editions#Comparison_chart So will this code work on Windows RT?

Comment: @NikeStrike I don't know. It's not released yet, and there are no public prereleases. I could take a guess, but that probably wouldn't be useful.